# Javascript button colour change not working with hex code?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, background-color

I'm working on a project where subscribers to a site can choose between a monthly and yearly subscription. The user has to choose their subscription type by clicking on a monthly or yearly button (Button code below)

```
<!-- Select Subscription Instructions -->
<p class="mb-0">
    <strong>Select your subscription type then click subscribe:</strong>
</p>

<!-- Yearly Subscription Button -->
<button id="yearly_subscription_selected" class="btn mr-2" type="submit" onclick="">
    Yearly Membership: £41.50 plus VAT
</button>

<!-- Monthly Subscription Button -->
<button id="monthly_subscription_selected" class="btn my-2" type="submit" onclick="">
    Monthly Membership: £8.25 plus VAT
</button>
```

When the user clicks on one of these buttons the `href=""` behind the subscribe button will change (This is working correctly)

I also want the membership button the user clicks on to change the background colour while the unselected membership button remains white. I have used the following JS code for this:

```
// Membership select Year JS 
document.getElementById("yearly_subscription_selected").onclick = function () {
  let link = document.getElementById("abc");
  link.setAttribute("href", "https://www.checkouty.htm");
  document.getElementById("yearly_subscription_selected").setAttribute("style", "background-color: green; color: #fff");
  if (document.getElementById("yearly_subscription_selected").style.backgroundColor == "green") {
    document.getElementById("monthly_subscription_selected").setAttribute("style", "background-color: white; color: #000");
  }
  return false;
}

// Membership select Month JS
document.getElementById("monthly_subscription_selected").onclick = function () {
  let link = document.getElementById("abc");
  link.setAttribute("href", "https://www.checkoutm.htm");
  document.getElementById("monthly_subscription_selected").setAttribute("style", "background-color: green; color: #fff");
  if (document.getElementById("monthly_subscription_selected").style.backgroundColor == "green") {
    document.getElementById("yearly_subscription_selected").setAttribute("style", "background-color: white; color: #000");
  }
  return false;
}
```

This code above is working and when the user selects a membership option the selected option button will turn green and the none selected button will turn white. However, if I change the `background-color: "green";` and replace it with the hex colour code `background-color: #bf1363` then the JS stops working and when you click on both buttons to switch between the memberships both buttons turn the same colour #bf1363.

```
// Membership select Year JS 
document.getElementById("yearly_subscription_selected").onclick = function () {
  let link = document.getElementById("abc");
  link.setAttribute("href", "https://www.checkouty.htm");
  document.getElementById("yearly_subscription_selected").setAttribute("style", "background-color: #bf1363; color: #fff");
  if (document.getElementById("yearly_subscription_selected").style.backgroundColor == "#bf1363") {
    document.getElementById("monthly_subscription_selected").setAttribute("style", "background-color: white; color: #000");
  }
  return false;
}

// Membership select Month JS
document.getElementById("monthly_subscription_selected").onclick = function () {
  let link = document.getElementById("abc");
  link.setAttribute("href", "https://www.checkoutm.htm");
  document.getElementById("monthly_subscription_selected").setAttribute("style", "background-color: #bf1363; color: #fff");
  if (document.getElementById("monthly_subscription_selected").style.backgroundColor == "#bf1363") {
    document.getElementById("yearly_subscription_selected").setAttribute("style", "background-color: white; color: #000");
  }
  return false;
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?? I'm using bootstrap 4 and vanilla JS

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do:

```
document.getElementById("yearly_subscription_selected").style.backgroundColor = "#bf1363";
console.log(document.getElementById("yearly_subscription_selected").style.backgroundColor);
```

It will return:

```
rgb(191, 19, 99)
```

So you can't compare that value with your string `#bf1363` that's just one of the many ways to encode a color value.

### Refactor

Anyway since your code had so many repetitions and was directly changing the element style instead of using css classes, I took the chance to better refactor your code to show that the same result could be achieved differently.

Here you have two css classes `btn-subscription` and `active`. The first is styling the button when it still isn't active (white bg) and the second one will style the button as active (purple bg).

Plus each of those buttons store the url where the link is supposed to point at as a `data-url` attribute.

That way you can have a single event handler that will deal with the click event occurring on both the buttons:

```js
let link = document.getElementById("abc");

//selects all the `.btn-subscription` elements
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-subscription')
  //for each one of them as btn    
  .forEach( btn => {
    //adds the click event handler
    btn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{  
      //the currently clicked button
      const clickedButton = event.target;
      
      //changes the href attribute of link as the data-url of the currently clicked btn
      link.setAttribute("href", clickedButton.dataset.url);
      
      //removes the active class from the first element .btn-subscription having it (if any)
      document.querySelector('.btn-subscription.active')?.classList.remove('active');
      //adds the class active only to the currently clicked button
      clickedButton.classList.add('active');  
    });    
  });
```

```css
#abc{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border: solid;
  padding: 1em;
}

/*just to show on screen the href attribute value*/
#abc::before{
  border: dashed 3px lightgray;
  content: "href: " attr(href);
  display: block;  
  padding: 4px .5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.btn-subscription{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: #000;
}

.active{
  background-color: #bf1363;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- Select Subscription Instructions -->
<p class="mb-0">
    <strong>Select your subscription type then click subscribe:</strong>
</p>

<!-- Yearly Subscription Button -->
<button
  id="yearly_subscription_selected"
  class="btn mr-2 btn-subscription"
  type="button"
  data-url="https://www.checkouty.htm">
    Yearly Membership: £41.50 plus VAT
</button>

<!-- Monthly Subscription Button -->
<button
  id="monthly_subscription_selected"
  class="btn my-2 btn-subscription"
  type="button"
  data-url="https://www.checkoutm.htm">
    Monthly Membership: £8.25 plus VAT
</button>

<a id="abc" href="">Link target element</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Diego. I'll use the rgb moving forward instead of HEX

Comment: I did the refactor also to show that it's a very bad practice to do like that because you are using the color value as a state and there's no reason. Usually classes are used for that .. or data attributes. The styling should be decoupled. But your code your choices. Anyway now you have your code coupled with a colour and you can't change that without changing the code